# All errors appear as ImproperlyConfigured exception in Pycharm run console

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I've had a problem which I think is a configuration issue with my Pycharm installation or environment, but I've re-downloaded pycharm with different versions and it doesn't work.

My problem is, that every error I get (any exception) is not properly informed to me in the run console. So, for example, if I have faulty code like:

```
value = 5
print(value)
```

The run console wouldn't display the correct error *(ValueError)*, but instead, this:

[image]

The console displays that error whenever I get **any** error. When there is no error, the code runs perfectly fine, and I know the error is not on my urls.py being misconfigured, I checked many times, and it runs fine on my co-workers machines. I haven't been able to find any information on this issue, which I find very strange. I can work on the project, but whenever there's an error, I have trouble finding it and therefore fixing it.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm a bit lost here.

I'm using Python 3.6, PyCharm version 2019.3.1, and Windows 10.

Comment: What is the file name from where you are running the above code?

Comment: It is a django project which I run with the pycharm "run" option. The last time an error appeared was when I added a new app called 'chatbot', with just urls.py and views.py, but it's imported from my co-workers repo, so I don't think that's the issue. And, also, this error has appeared before because of errors on different parts of the code.

Comment: The above error trace is due to either a missing url.py or inside the url.py, url_pattern is not initialised, so inside url.py add url_pattern=[]; urlpattern=[]

Comment: In the urls.py of each app in the project (and the urls.py of the project itself), all of them have a "urlpatterns=[...]" statment.

Comment: Check if the patterns inside the urlpattern list are all valid as that causes the same error

Comment: I checked, and they seem fine. And if that was the issue, it wouldn't work on my co-workers computers, or would it?

Comment: Then first thing I'd try would be to comment out the references to quiniela.views. If it still doesn't work. comment out the include of quiniela.urls